# How to hide the View After clear the textfield data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I  want to hide the View after clear the Text field data.But My view is not hiding.Please give me the solution i am using this code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    partialSearchView.hidden = YES;
    isCheckType = YES;

    return  YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    partialSearchView.hidden = NO;
    isCheckType = NO;

    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: Try partialSearchView.alpha = 1; if you want to show it and partialSearchView.alpha = 0; for hiding.

Comment: My guess is that partialSearchView is nil.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the setter method: ...

```
  [self.partialSearchView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: `partialSearchView.hidden = YES;` is *exactly* equivalent to `[partialSearchView setHidden:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
```

The text field calls this method in response to the user pressing the built-in clear button. (This button is not shown by default but can be enabled by changing the value in the clearButtonMode property of the text field.) This method is also called when editing begins and the clearsOnBeginEditing property of the text field is set to YES.

Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional. If it is not present, the text is cleared as if this method had returned YES.

you need actually implementation

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
     partialSearchView.hidden = YES;
     isCheckType = YES;

     return YES;
 }

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


    if (isCheckType )
         return YES;
    partialSearchView.hidden = NO;
    isCheckType = NO;

    if (textField.text.length >=8) {
         return NO; // return NO to not change text
    } else { 
         return YES;
    }
 }
```